# SQL name in list of items

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, one containing a path and the other containing a filename. Here's an example:

```
t1
- file.mov
- myfile.txt
- 2file.py

t2
- /new/path/file.mov
- /path/hello.txt
- /path/2file.py
```

I want to build a query to get me all the filenames for which I have a path:

```
- file.mov    /new/path/file.mov
- 2file.py      /path/2file.py
```

What would be the query I could use to find this? The closest I could think of is using `IN`, but that is based on an exact match and not a `LIKE`, which is what I need to use:

```
SELECT name FROM names WHERE name in (SELECT path FROM paths);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an `INNER JOIN` between to 2 tables will allow you to list either or both the file names and paths

```
SELECT names.name, paths.path
FROM names 
INNER JOIN paths ON names.name = SUBSTRING_INDEX(paths.path, '/', -1) 
;
```

However the output will be (from the sample):

```
|     NAME |               PATH |
|----------|--------------------|
| file.mov | /new/path/file.mov |
| 2file.py |     /path/2file.py |
```

because you do not have a path for "myfile.txt", or a name for "/path/hello.txt", (so this result does not match the result shown in the question).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name 
FROM names 
WHERE name in 
    (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(path, '/', -1) FROM paths);
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned using LIKE - combining that with EXISTS could work. E.g.

```
SELECT name
FROM names
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM paths
    WHERE path LIKE '%' + name
)
```

Just keep in mind that this has the potential to return false positives, i.e. if your paths table contained "path/2file.py", and you searched for "file.py".